# How to Remove box icon above the search icon in lightning

Tags: lightning

[image: highlighted box]

I am getting the box icon above the search icon.How to remove it.Below is my code.

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-lookup" data-select="single">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">

            <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"

                                 placeholder="search Accounts.."
                                 aura:id="searchField"
                                 label="Account Name"
                                 class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input slds-p-bottom_medium"
                                 />

            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:search" onclick="{!c.Search}" alternativeText="Search" class="slds-input__icon slds-p-top_small" />

            </div>  

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using padding in bottom- slds-p-bottom_medium. Use the following code, It may help you:[image]

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-lookup" data-select="single">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
                <div>
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:search" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.Search }" alternativeText="Search" class="slds-input__icon" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ui:inputText value="{!v.searchKeyword}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont wanna dig deep in SLDS css issues and  can use ui:inputText instead of lightning:input, you can get it sorted in few lines.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-lookup" data-select="single">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
                <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:search" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" alternativeText="Search" class="slds-input__icon" />
                <ui:inputText value="{!v.searchText}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

And this code is refrenced from https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/communities_theme_layout/custom_search

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response.The issue is with label.if we mention label inside the input search bar the search icon will loose its actual position.